# how to get image brightness and contrast in jquery

Tags: jquery, brightness

Is there any way to get image brightness and contrast using jQuery ?

I have to change Image brightness and contrast using Jquery.So first I want to see what is default brightness and contrast of image is.

Comment: They are usually properties display devices.. I'm positive you dont have *default brightness and contrast* for images..

Comment: jQuery wasn't designed to manipulate images (or discover their properties, beyond width and height)

Comment: canvas html5 looks better for this

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to adjust brightness/contrast of image using slider ?

Comment: No, we can have any idea because slider means nothing (or means lot of things)

Comment: There are ways to *'how to adjust brightness/contrast of image'.* But you'd need to do the research to find them out for yourself.

Comment: Slider - by which We can increase or decrease value of brightness (input type="range") .

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest to use a [prerolled JS library](http://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/demo/)...

Comment: thanks for this url @Shanimal. I was looking something like it since morning and just got Pixastic but it's not working fine for me. I am going to try it which you suggest me If any problem occurs Please help me.

Comment: @user2307273 there are many good libraries out there, some solutions are on the server side. I usually prefer the browser based solutions but if you need compatiblity across devices (ios) and older browsers you should go with a server side solution.

Comment: @Shanimal Please give me server side solutions too.

Comment: This glfx.js does not support webGl and it is problem in most of the browser. Please give me any other solution.

Comment: There's options out there. a) pixastic (as you mentioned) b) detect WebGL and instruct users to turn it on c) server side (imagemagick, imagefilter, etc...) d) flash (which  I used to develop 2d+3d photo transitions professionally for several years e) css filters. Which direction do you want to go?